# How to create an Atom RSS feed with site's content type?

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a content type named "blog" of drupal 7 website. How to create Atom RSS feed with site's blog?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) + [Views Atom](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_atom) to create XML feeds.

[image]

Comment: Your solution is for rss feed. But I need to fetch **Atom feed** which is different from **RSS feed**. Both are different take a look [here](https://shafiq2410.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/rss-vs-atom-which-one-is-better/). I'm using [Feeds_Atom](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_atom) and [View Atom](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_atom). Please help if have any experience in this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can have a look on other modules https://www.drupal.org/project/views_atom and https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_atom

Comment: In view, I have setup fields as [Atom Feed - Fields](http://screencast.com/t/VIKVyVXlOsg). But error is "Feed" is missing required atom fields: Title, URL, Updated. In fields setting the configuration is [this](http://screencast.com/t/ly4gBVLIeTM).

Comment: In the Atom Feed - Fields -> settings -> Field Usage, set URL, Title, Updated. Then you will not get that error

Comment: I did [setting](http://screencast.com/t/mk150PxI) as you suggested but after save on setting shows [error](http://screencast.com/t/QDIPfgCq).

Comment: I even got that error, may be query fault or something missing. can you please have a look any patches available. Go the module issues and check if any one reported